# Chewy gem deserializes Elasticsearch date types to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chewy-gem

When retrieving results from ES using Chewy, the date-typed results are returned as Ruby strings.

My index is defined just like:

```
class OrdersIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type Order do

    field :id, type: "keyword"
    field :created_at, type: "date"
  end
end
```

When the results are retrieved:

```
OrdersIndex.order(created_at: :desc).first.created_at.class
# => String
```

Is there a way to deserialize this date field in a Ruby date object automatically, without having to explicitly map the results using `Time#parse`?

Comment: Having the same problem. Very strange and unexpected behavior.